# Image library to download and show images from Amazon S3

Tags: android, image, amazon-s3

I need to create one smooth and nice image gallery (images in a GridView and each image can be zoomed in viewpager (swipe left/right) ) in my android application.

My pictures are available to be downloaded on Amazon S3.

Now, my question is what is the best way to download pictures from S3 and show them. For the moment, I am downloading the pictures from S3 (if they are not yet on sd card, with their library, TransferManager, in an asynctask), once downloaded to a specific folder in SD Card, I am showing the image through UNiversalImageLoader library. But I find the process a bit slow, and not so smooth, app is bugging a bit when there are a few images to be loaded (even if they are already downloaded to sd card). What should I change in my process ? Is it better to generate a dynamic url with amazon and then download it through a library? Is it the File.exists check (to see if I have to download pic or not) which is slow?

I need the following features for my gallery:
- view images in gallery (gridview)
- see if images are on sd card, if not download from s3, if on sd card, show them in gallery
- download to specific sd card location
- view each image in viewpager (swipe left/right)

Thanks for your help,

Henry

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) library. It is used to load and cache images you don't have to manage the image cache, the library does that for you. Example as follows,

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Does it cache the images on disk? How can I download images from amazon s3 with that?

Comment: Give your amazon s3 image url as argument to `load()` function. It will download and cache the images.

Comment: Yes, but I have to generate a dynamic url which is available for 1 min for example (because the images are private), so do you think the cache will works correctly with dynamic url? Can we specify a specific place on the disk to cache?

Comment: `Picasso` does that automatically.

Comment: Ok, nice, thanks :) The only problem that I see with this solution is how to avoid to generate the dynamic URL (which takes few seconds) if the image is already downloaded and can be showed.. We will loose time by generating each dynamic URL for each image.. Or we have to keep a copy of the link ?

Comment: If you want to update the image in the client each time it changes, its better that you generate the dynamic URL for each image.

Comment: No, the image never changes on the server, so if the image was previously downloaded, I don't have to generate the dynamic URL as it is already downloaded (and the dynamic URL is only for downloading), but how I can I know if the images is already cached as I don't have the link and don't wanna loose time to generate URL for already downloaded image ? + If I don't have internet, I should be able to see the previously downloaded image (I don't know if this is possible with Picasso) :)

Comment: That is what caching means, maintaining a copy of an image locally when there is no internet. Find more info in the documentation. Good luck. :)

Comment: quick question here. I am also trying to do something similar. How do i get the s3 image's url? (a reference to that url)?

Comment: @TheQ You will have to provide the url to `Picasso` from an API (if the image url is dynamic) or you can hardcode the image if its static.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial to download the image from [S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html)

Comment: @KNeerajLal so, for my use case, the images will not be static, therefore i cannot hard code them in. What api did you use to get the image URL? Or, how did you generate that api? In that tutorial, it shows you how to download the image into your phone. I don't want to download every image, i just want to have it in my app locally so i can put them in imageviews.

Comment: @TheQ I made the API to store and retrieve the image urls from s3. Whenever I uploaded to s3, I stored the urls in my online DB and later retrieved it when I wanted to display it.